# Localization of Audio

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, audio, localization

First of all i am a n00b.
After 3 days of trying and research i decided to get some external help.

What i did and my Project:

i make a book for children.
Now i am localizing my app.
for a Image i did it like this:

```
UIImage *schrift = [UIImage imageNamed:NSLocalizedString (@"Schrift_en.png", nil)];
image = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:schrift];
image.frame = CGRectMake(75.5, 80, 617, 137);
[self.view addSubview:image];
[image release];
```

works great for me :)

Now i am trying to do the same with my Narrator Audiofile but can´t figure out how.

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Vorwort" ofType:@"mp3"];
AVAudioPlayer* theAudio = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL   fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];
self.audioPlayer = theAudio;
[theAudio release];
```

How can i change the code above to make it work and how to define ofType:@"mp3" in Localizable.strings-file?

Google can´t help me.
Any ideas?
slowly but surely i am losing my motivation.

It would be really cool if anyone could help me!
Thanks in advance
Planky

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath], NSLocalizedString (@"audiofilename.mp3", nil)]];

AVAudioPlayer* theAudio = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:NULL];
self.audioPlayer = theAudio;
[theAudio release];
```

Answer (score 3):

This isn't really what Localizable.strings is for. Check out the docs for NSBundle's [pathForResource:ofType:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSBundle_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000214-BCIBAHJF)

> The method first looks for a matching resource file in the non-localized resource directory of the specified bundle. (… in iOS, it is the main bundle directory.) If a matching resource file is not found, it then looks in the top level of any available language-specific “.lproj” directories. (The search order for the language-specific directories corresponds to the user’s preferences.) It does not recurse through other subdirectories at any of these locations.

So if you previously had your audio file here:

```
YourBook.app/Vorwort.mp3
```

you should instead arrange it like this:

```
YourBook.app/en.lproj/Vorwort.mp3
YourBook.app/fr.lproj/Vorwort.mp3
```

No Volwort.mp3 should exists at the top level of the .app folder.

You will need to create the en.lroj/fr.lproj directories and drag them to your XCode project. Check your app bundle structure by right clicking on the .app in the Finder and clicking 'Show bundle contents'.